# Does word syntax take script into account?

Tags: syntax

I call `count-words-region` (<kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>) on US/RU/IPA string:

```
HelloПривheləʊ
```

The following message is printed:

```
Region has 1 line, 4 words, and 14 characters.
```

All symbols have `w` syntax, but differ in script:

```
(char-syntax ?H) ; ?w
(char-syntax ?П) ; ?w
(char-syntax ?ʊ) ; ?w
(aref char-script-table ?H)  ; script: latin
(aref char-script-table ?П)  ; script: cyrillic
(aref char-script-table ?ʊ)  ; script: phonetic
```

Does that mean that word boundary is defined not only by **char syntax** but also by **char script**?

I would like to disable this behavior for selected modes in order to be able to navigate across words but not across scripts. How can this be achieved?

**UPDATE** [Useful further discussion on debbugs](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24405).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This specific behaviour of `forward-word` can be controlled by the variables `word-combining-categories` and `word-separating-categories`. If you want to ignore the script completely, it is sufficient to add the pair (nil . nil) to the first list, e.g.

```
(let ((word-combining-categories (cons '(nil . nil)
                                       word-combining-categories)))
  (forward-word))
```

You can also change that variable with `setq-local` if you want the effect in a specific buffer.

Comment: How did you find about these variables? I see no mention of them in the elisp manual...

Comment: @JeanPierre I looked at the source (and 100% agree that it should be documented!)

Comment: Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` to have the documentation updated.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `forward-word` and `backward-word` also show there are several words here.  It does make sense to me that characters from different scripts can't be in the same word, but the documentation should be made explicit about that ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Word-Motion.html#Word-Motion)).  I suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug` about it.

If you just want to move accross "words" ignoring script, you can use `skip-syntax-forward` and `skip-syntax-backward` (described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Motion-and-Syntax.html#Motion-and-Syntax))