# Why does forward-word stop at this quotation mark?

Tags: syntax, emacs-internals, emacs24

Minimal example code, run it from `emacs -Q`.  Note the use of unicode RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (’) not APOSTROPHE (').

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?’ "w p" text-mode-syntax-table) ; that's the same syntax as '
(progn
  (switch-to-buffer "test")
  (text-mode)
  (insert "this isn’t a word character?")
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (forward-word 2))
```

In my Emacs (version 24.5.1) this leaves point on the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK in “isn’t”.  Why?  Shouldn't it move point between “isn’t” and “a” instead?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/21131 . Please confirm.

Comment: Holy cow, yes, that's exactly what's going on.  Thanks for the pointer!